# Matlab: Nonlinear equation solver

Tags: matlab

How do I solve these sets of equations and can matlab find a solution? I'm solving for x1,x2,x3,x4,c1,c2,c3,c4.

```
syms c1 c2 c3 c4 x1 x2 x3 x4;
eqn1 = c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 == 2;
eqn2 = c1*x1 + c2*x2 + c3*x3 + c4*x4 == 0; 
eqn3 = c1*x1^2 + c2*x2^2 + c3*x3^2 + c4*x4^2 == 2/3;
eqn4 = c1*x1^3 + c2*x2^3 + c3*x3^3 + c4*x4^3 == 0;
eqn5 = c1*x1^4 + c2*x2^4 + c3*x3^4 + c4*x4^4 == 2/5; 
eqn6 = c1*x1^5 + c2*x2^5 + c3*x3^5 + c4*x4^5 == 0;
eqn7 = c1*x1^6 + c2*x2^6 + c3*x3^6 + c4*x4^6 == 2/7;
eqn8 = c1*x1^7 + c2*x2^7 + c3*x3^7 + c4*x4^7 == 0;
```

From what I understand, matlab has fsolve, solve, and linsolve, but I'm uncertain how to use them.

Comment: I think you need a non-linear constrained optimization.   Your eqn1 is one constraint on the constants.  If it were a linear problem I'd say simplex.  You need a non-linear algorithm, maybe a simulated annealing.  https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/nonlinear-programming.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a system of non-linear equations, so you can use [fsolve](http://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) to find a solution.

First of all you need to create a function, say `fcn`, of a variable `x`, where `x` is a vector with your initial point. The function defines an output vector, depending on the current vector `x`.

You have eight variables, so your vector `x` will consist of eight elements. Let's rename your variables in this way:

```
%x1 x(1)      %c1 x(5)
%x2 x(2)      %c2 x(6)
%x3 x(3)      %c3 x(7)
%x4 x(4)      %c4 x(8)
```

Your function will look like this:

```
function F = fcn(x)

    F=[x(5) +          x(6)         + x(7)         + x(8)        - 2   ;
       x(5)*x(1)    +  x(6)*x(2)    + x(7)*x(3)    + x(8)*x(4)         ;
       x(5)*x(1)^2  +  x(6)*x(2)^2  + x(7)*x(3)^2  + x(8)*x(4)^2 - 2/3 ;
       x(5)*x(1)^3  +  x(6)*x(2)^3  + x(7)*x(3)^3  + x(8)*x(4)^3       ;
       x(5)*x(1)^4  +  x(6)*x(2)^4  + x(7)*x(3)^4  + x(8)*x(4)^4 - 2/5 ;
       x(5)*x(1)^5  +  x(6)*x(2)^5  + x(7)*x(3)^5  + x(8)*x(4)^5       ;
       x(5)*x(1)^6  +  x(6)*x(2)^6  + x(7)*x(3)^6  + x(8)*x(4)^6 - 2/7 ;
       x(5)*x(1)^7  +  x(6)*x(2)^7  + x(7)*x(3)^7  + x(8)*x(4)^7
       ];
end
```

You can evaluate your function with some initial value of `x`:

```
x0  = [1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1];

F0 = fcn(x0);
```

Using `x0` as initial point your function returns:

```
F0 =

    2.0000
    4.0000
    3.3333
    4.0000
    3.6000
    4.0000
    3.7143
    4.0000
```

Now you can start `fsolve` which will try to find some vector `x`, such as your function returns all zeros:

```
[x,fval]=fsolve(@fcn, x0);
```

You will get something like this:

```
x =

    0.7224
    0.7224
   -0.1100
   -0.7589
    0.3599
    0.3599
    0.6794
    0.5768

fval =

   -0.0240
    0.0075
    0.0493
    0.0183
   -0.0126
   -0.0036
   -0.0733
   -0.0097
```

As you can see, the function values are really close to zeros, but you probably noticed that the optimization algorithm was stopped because of the limited count of the function evaluation steps stored in `options.MaxFunEvals` (by default `800`). Another possible reason is the limited number of iterations stored in `MaxIter` (by default `400`).

Redefine these value using the parameter `options`:

```
options = optimset('MaxFunEvals',2000, 'MaxIter', 1000);

[x,fval]=fsolve(@fcn, x0, options);
```

Now your output is much better:

```
x =

    0.7963
    0.7963
   -0.0049
   -0.7987
    0.2619
    0.2619
    0.9592
    0.5165
fval =

   -0.0005
   -0.0000
   -0.0050
    0.0014
    0.0208
   -0.0001
   -0.0181
   -0.0007
```

Just play with different parameter values, in order to achieve a tolerable precision level for your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it Anton!