# Matlab: Nonlinear Eq: error

Tags: matlab

I have the code from a previous question, however, this one is similar, just more equations added. However, I get an error and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Link to my previous question: [Matlab: Nonlinear equation solver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387797/matlab-nonlinear-equation-solver)

```
    function F = fcn(x)

    F=[x(6) +          x(7)         + x(8)         + x(9)        + x(10)         - 2   ;
       x(6)*x(1)    +  x(7)*x(2)    + x(8)*x(3)    + x(9)*x(4)   + x(10)*x(5)          ;
       x(6)*x(1)^2  +  x(7)*x(2)^2  + x(8)*x(3)^2  + x(9)*x(4)^2 + x(10)*x(5)    - 2/3 ;
       x(6)*x(1)^3  +  x(7)*x(2)^3  + x(8)*x(3)^3  + x(9)*x(4)^3 + x(10)*x(5)          ;
       x(6)*x(1)^4  +  x(7)*x(2)^4  + x(8)*x(3)^4  + x(9)*x(4)^4 + x(10)*x(5)     -2/5 ;
       x(6)*x(1)^5  +  x(7)*x(2)^5  + x(8)*x(3)^5  + x(9)*x(4)^5 + x(10)*x(5)          ;
       x(6)*x(1)^6  +  x(7)*x(2)^6  + x(8)*x(3)^6  + x(9)*x(4)^6 + x(10)*x(5)     -2/7 ;
       x(6)*x(1)^7  +  x(7)*x(2)^7  + x(8)*x(3)^7  + x(9)*x(4)^7 + x(10)*x(5)          ;
       x(6)*x(1)^8  +  x(7)*x(2)^8  + x(8)*x(3)^8  + x(9)*x(4)^8 + x(10)*x(5)     -2/9 ;
       x(6)*x(1)^9  +  x(7)*x(2)^9  + x(8)*x(3)^9  + x(9)*x(4)^9 + x(10)*x(5)          

       ];

    end




clc
clear all;
format long

x0  = [0.9; 0.5; 0.1; -0.5; -0.9; 0.2; 0.4; 0.5; 0.4; 0.2]; %Guess

F0 = fcn(x0);

[x,fval]=fsolve(@fcn, x0) %solve without optimization

options = optimset('MaxFunEvals',10000, 'MaxIter', 10000); %optimization criteria

[x,fval]=fsolve(@fcn, x0, options) %solve with optimization
```

The error that I get are:

Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in fcn(line 4) %This is from the function script
    F=[x(6) +          x(7)         + x(8)         + x(9)        + x(10)
    - 2   ;

Error in fcncall (line 7) %This is from the main script
F0 = fcn(x0);

Comment: Thank you everyone. Wow, talk about subtle mistakes.

Comment: While technically this is a "problem due to a typo", I believe it would be instructive to keep this question open for future reference (unless an earlier question is found which can be a duplicate), mostly as a dupe target.

Comment: In agreement with @AndrasDeak.  I don't really consider this a typographical error but more an extreme subtly in the grammar of the Matlab language that even advanced users (pointing at myself) have and may fall victim to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very subtle error I've encountered before.  When creating an array literal as you are doing `fcn`, negative signs that are directly attached to numbers and preceded by a space, as in rows 5, 7, and 9 of your array literal, are viewed as unary operators (i.e., the `-` makes the number negative and does not act as a binary minus operation).  Therefore, because Matlab allows the delimiting of columns to be made with spaces, the indicated rows are interpreted to have two columns; row 5 column 1 is `x(6)*x(1)^4 ... x(10)*x(5)`, and row 5 column 2 is `-2/5`.

So, either put a space between the three numbers or eliminate all spaces between the minus signs.  For example:

```
x(6)*x(1)^4  +  x(7)*x(2)^4  + x(8)*x(3)^4  + x(9)*x(4)^4 + x(10)*x(5)     - 2/5;
```

or

```
x(6)*x(1)^4  +  x(7)*x(2)^4  + x(8)*x(3)^4  + x(9)*x(4)^4 + x(10)*x(5)-2/5;
```

Answer (score 1):

That problem wasn't easy to find. Not using a blank before the minus at the end of the rows, you created a row with two elements instead of one. For a simplified example compare this:

```
>> [2 - 2]

ans =

     0

>> [2 -2]

ans =

     2    -2

>> [(2 -2)]

ans =

     0
```

Now the corrected version of your code:

```
  F=[x(6) +          x(7)         + x(8)         + x(9)        + x(10)         - 2   ;
   x(6)*x(1)    +  x(7)*x(2)    + x(8)*x(3)    + x(9)*x(4)   + x(10)*x(5)          ;
   x(6)*x(1)^2  +  x(7)*x(2)^2  + x(8)*x(3)^2  + x(9)*x(4)^2 + x(10)*x(5)    - 2/3 ; ...either set a space
   x(6)*x(1)^3  +  x(7)*x(2)^3  + x(8)*x(3)^3  + x(9)*x(4)^3 + x(10)*x(5)          ;
   (x(6)*x(1)^4  +  x(7)*x(2)^4  + x(8)*x(3)^4  + x(9)*x(4)^4 + x(10)*x(5)    -2/5); ...or use brackets
   x(6)*x(1)^5  +  x(7)*x(2)^5  + x(8)*x(3)^5  + x(9)*x(4)^5 + x(10)*x(5)          ; ...both fixes the problem
   x(6)*x(1)^6  +  x(7)*x(2)^6  + x(8)*x(3)^6  + x(9)*x(4)^6 + x(10)*x(5)    - 2/7 ;
   x(6)*x(1)^7  +  x(7)*x(2)^7  + x(8)*x(3)^7  + x(9)*x(4)^7 + x(10)*x(5)          ;
   x(6)*x(1)^8  +  x(7)*x(2)^8  + x(8)*x(3)^8  + x(9)*x(4)^8 + x(10)*x(5)    - 2/9 ;
   x(6)*x(1)^9  +  x(7)*x(2)^9  + x(8)*x(3)^9  + x(9)*x(4)^9 + x(10)*x(5)          ];
```